# How does git work (BitBucket) when collaborators commit different changes?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Suppose three people (X, Y and Z) are collaborating on a project on BitBucket. Here's the sequence of events that takes place:

1. X creates the project and clones to his local machine
2. Y also clones the project to his local machine
3. X makes changes to the project on his local machine, then does a git commit, and a git push to BitBucket
4. Y makes different changes to the project, and also does a git commit and git push
5. Z clones the project to his local machine

What does Z have on his machine? Does he have both X and Y's changes, or just Y's changes?

Comment: This is pretty basic Git usage, that any tutorial should cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Y can push his changes he has to merge them with X changes. When he tries to push he will get an error.

In most cases it is sufficient for Y to just `git pull` to merge.

Z will see both changes.